# Target.Formula contains a cell reference. How to get the cell reference right next to it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro activated by editing column 1 in - e.g. - `thisSheet`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        MsgBox (Target.Formula)
    End If
End Sub
```

E.g. after editing `thisSheet!A$1` the message box shows `=otherSheet!C$123` which is fine

Now I need the macro automaticaly write into `thisSheet!B$1` the formula `otherSheet!D$123`. Simply, I want to enter the cell references of a row in `otherSheet` into a row of `thisSheet`
Here is a small example what I need

Step 1, `otherSheet`is const, `thisSheet` is empty.

```
otherSheet                   thisSheet
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
   | C     | D     | E        | A               | B               | C
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
123|valueA1|valueB1|valueC1  1|                 |                 |
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
124|valueA2|valueB2|valueC2  2|                 |                 |
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
```

Step 2, `otherSheet` is const, `thisSheet` edited manually by hand

```
otherSheet                   thisSheet
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
   | C     | D     | E        | A               | B               | C
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
123|valueA1|valueB1|valueC1  1|=otherSheet!C$123|                 |
-+-------+-------+-------    -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
124|valueA2|valueB2|valueC2  2|                 |                 |
-+-------+-------+-------    -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
```

Step 3, `otherSheet` is const, `thisSheet` edited automatically by macro

```
otherSheet                   thisSheet
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
   | C     | D     | E        | A               | B               | C
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
123|valueA1|valueB1|valueC1  1|=otherSheet!C$123|=otherSheet!D$123|=otherSheet!E$123
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
124|valueA2|valueB2|valueC2  2|                 |                 |
---+-------+-------+-------  -+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
```

How to do this?

Comment: I,m not sure I understand the question. `Worksheets("thisSheet").Range("B1").Formula = "=otherSheet!D$123"`? Or are you asking about how to vary the formula depending on the cell?

Comment: can't you just Fill Right? The column in that formula is relative.

Comment: There's a lot going on in this question - the title asks one question and the body asks another. what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. But do you mean every time A is changed you want to copy it across a further column? Or what determines how far it goes across?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Target.Copy Target.Offset(, 1) 'copied to B
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good. Yes, indeed, every time A changes, I want to copy some parts of the row. Waitng to be able to accept it in some minutes